# changing frame of tableView to show and hide a search bar

Tags: ios, hide, tableview, uisearchbar

I am using storyboards. Im trying to dynamically change the frame of a UItableView within a view controller. I have a search bar above a tableView within a view controller. the search bar should only be visible under certain conditions, so most of the time I want to hide it

When the view loads I hide the search bar, then set the frame of my tableView so that it moves up to fill in the missing space. However it does not look like my table view frame is being updated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
//hide the search bar until the user selects search
    self.searchBar.hidden = YES;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y - self.searchBar.frame.size.height, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height + self.searchBar.frame.size.height);

}
```

Is there another method or something I need to call so that the frame of my tableView gets updated? thanks

edit: ive also  tried adding the search bar as the header view for the table in my storyboard, and then setting the headerView to nil initially like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;


    //hide the search bar until the user selects search
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;


}
```

but when I try to make it appear again using

```
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

it does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working using the table header view. I needed to make my search bar strong so that the view didnt get released when it was set to nil.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

then to show and hide it just set the header to nil to hide or assign it the searchBar to show it

```
 //hide the search bar
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;

 //show the search bar
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```